# Possible reasons for PC turning off when Veracrypt's pre-boot authentication prompt is left alone for a few minutes?

Tags: bios, uefi, shutdown, veracrypt

I have a PC based on a Supermicro X9SRi-F mainboard. I have put the firmware in UEFI mode and have installed Windows 10 Enterprise 1909. Then I have installed Veracrypt 1.24 Update 4 and have encrypted the system partition.

In general, the PC works without any issues if used normally. However, I (accidentally) have noticed the following weird behavior which I very much would like to have an explanation for:

If I turn on that PC by pressing the power button, let it boot until Veracrypt's pre-boot authentication password prompt and *at that prompt do nothing* (notably, do *not* type the password), the PC turns off after two or three minutes.

I would like to stress again that everything is normal if I *do* type the password as soon as that prompt appears. Windows then boots and works normally; there are no unexpected shutdowns and no other issues once Windows has started, regardless whether I leave it alone or use it continuously.

What could be the reason for the PC turning off at the Veracrypt pre-boot authentication password prompt? Actually, I even don't have any clue whether the shutdown is due to Veracrypt or due to the mainboard's firmware ...

What I already have tested / double-checked:

- We can rule out the mainboard's watchdog as possible reason, because I have disabled the watchdog in the BIOS.
- We can rule out overheating as possible reason, because the cooler is a Noctua NH-D15 which I have mounted very carefully. Furthermore, I have just run the torture test of Prime95 for several minutes and watched the CPU temperature using HWMonitor; the maximum temperature on the hottest core was 53° C during that test. So there are no issues with cooling.
- There are no entries in the mainboard's system event log (I had activated system event logging (SEL) in the mainboard's BIOS setup when building the PC in the first place).

Comment: Are you sure it isn't a setting of Veracrypt to do so? I.e. to turn off to save power in case it was accidentally booted up?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I was searching for several hours for that setting, in the software as well as by googling, but couldn't find it. Of course, I could have missed it, in which case I hope somebody tells me about it :-)

Comment: well theres this: https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Release%20Notes.html If you search for "Several enhancements and fixes for EFI bootloader" on that page it talks about the exact issue you have. As such I don't think its an issue, rather, the timeout has been programmed in. I don't know if you can change it...

Comment: I would also say that, since it is open source, you could just change the timeout or remove it altogether and recompile, while I know it is possible I don't know how to do it. It seems its part of the EFI bootloader and not an easily changed setting, so in effect after recompiling (if necessary) you'd need to install/overwrite the existing EFI VeraCrypt bootloader with your custom one. In my own personal opinion I think its a good idea it's there, in case the PC starts by WOL or something accidental. Also if it *does* time out it takes seconds to boot back up anyway. Just my 2 cents though

Comment: Wow, thanks so much! You have hit the nail right on the head. Despite my searching, I hadn't found that passage. You are completely right that this behavior actually makes sense, and indeed, I do not have any problem with it. I just needed to understand the reason, because I suspected something was wrong with the BIOS settings or the hardware.

Comment: And if you make your second comment an answer, I'll happily upvote and accept it. You have exactly answered my question (which was not how to disable that behavior, but how to explain it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://veracrypt.fr/en/Release%20Notes.html) page suggests that the behaviour you observe is indeed intended. On that page it talks about this timeout in the 7th point down in the Windows category ("Several enhancements and fixes for EFI bootloader", shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4wfm.png)).

Since Veracrypt is open source, you could just change the timeout or remove it altogether and recompile. It seems this behaviour part of the VeraCrypt EFI bootloader itself and not an easily changed setting in the program in the loaded OS, so in effect after recompiling (if necessary) you may need to install/overwrite the existing EFI VeraCrypt bootloader with your custom one as well.

(In my own personal opinion I think its a good idea this setting is there by default, in case the PC starts by WOL or something accidental. Also, if it does time out and shut down, it takes mere seconds to boot to that screen anyway)

Comment: Thank you very much. In addition, thanks to your help, I just have found https://sourceforge.net/p/veracrypt/discussion/features/thread/f57f345b/ - see the fourth post to see how the timeout and type of action can be changed. Cool ...

Comment: Ah, its part of a configuration file; you might not need to install a new bootloader then.